# Create lambdas that use *args in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, lambda

I've found some other questions that deal with the problem of creating lambdas inside loops, and the last value in the iteration being assigned to all lambda functions. While the solution is generally using `lambda x=x:` instead of `lambda x:`, or using `functools.partial`, what should I do when the lambda expects `*args`?

```
>>> keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for func in [lambda *args: print(x, args) for x in keys]:
...     func(1, 2, 3)
... 
c (1, 2, 3)
c (1, 2, 3)
c (1, 2, 3)
```

Expected result:

```
a (1, 2, 3)
b (1, 2, 3)
c (1, 2, 3)
```

The actual code is:

```
for event in emitter_events:
    self.ws.on(event, lambda *args: logging.debug(f"'{event}': {repr(args)}"))
```

Comment: `lambda x=x:` is a hack. In general, the "correct" solution is to force the closure to refer to a variable that does not change by creating another enclosing scope. One way, `lambda event: (lambda event: lambda *args: logging.debug(f"'{event}': {repr(args)}"))(event)`

Comment: However, it is better to create a factory function: `def make_func(event): return lambda *args: logging.debug(...)` and then use *that* in your loop: `self.ws.on(event, make_func(event))`

Comment: Note, all of this isn't really unique to lambda expressions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, that works! Why is the second option better, though?

Comment: Because it is much cleaner.